# Misalignment possibility on struct content made private through typedef to an array

Tags: c, arrays, struct, alignment, zeromq

I've used this interesting approach to make opaque and private structs:

```
struct s_vector_private
{
    size_t item_size;
    uint32_t used_slots;
    uint32_t buffer_total_slots;
    uint8_t * buffer;
};
typedef uint8_t vector_t[sizeof(struct s_vector_private)];
/* This code can be found at [1] */
```

This way, `vector_t` contents are private and `vector_t` can be allocated on heap and stack.

Recently I've wondered if allocating `vector_t`, either in stack or heap, can cause alignment problems since compiler sees it is an array instead of a struct.

For further enlightenment, there are big libraries that use this kind of approach, like zmq declaration of the `zmq_msg_t` type:

```
typedef struct zmq_msg_t {unsigned char _ [40];} zmq_msg_t; 
/* This code can be found at [2] */
```

In the zmq example, is it possible to get misaligned structures as well? I couldn't avoid noting that `zmq_msg_t` has declared the array inside of a struct, would this be a safe way to implement the technique in question here?

[1] http://github.com/felipe-lavratti/chelper/blob/master/include/chelper/helper_types.h, line 48.

[2] http://github.com/zeromq/libzmq/blob/master/include/zmq.h, line 202.

Comment: Yes, it can cause alignment problems.  Also, it's not clear in what sense the resulting type would be opaque.  It's also not entirely clear why 0MQ does that, because nothing in that header uses a `zmq_msg_t` by value.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth So, the verdict is that both approaches (mine and 0MQ's) could cause alignment problems? Any references or justification? Thanks.

Comment: The justification is that the C language standard gives no guarantees about the alignment of a `vector_t` (nor whether a `uint32_t`, etc. can be read mis-aligned).  On specific platforms, it may be fine, of course.

Comment: Answering your question, it will become opaque in sense of the user will use it without ever knowing it's content. Maybe opaque is not the right definition, I'm changing the title to "private" instead "opaque". Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posix c library uses the zmq mentioned technique to hide `struct` contents. To deal with alignment they do a union with the array. See ptread_mutexattr_t type below.

```
typedef union
{
  char __size[__SIZEOF_PTHREAD_MUTEXATTR_T];
  int __align;
} pthread_mutexattr_t;
```

This is an excellent approach to hide `struct` members, but there is one main drawback that may be significant if your code is not a library with slow releases. the size of the array has got to be a typed constant:

```
#ifdef __x86_64__
# if __WORDSIZE == 64
#  define __SIZEOF_PTHREAD_ATTR_T 56
#  define __SIZEOF_PTHREAD_MUTEX_T 40
#  define __SIZEOF_PTHREAD_MUTEXATTR_T 4
...
```

This is a considerable drawback in rapid changing modules, or code under development, since each time the `struct` internals are changed, this number must be manually update. Forgetting to do it will lead to undefined behaviour hard to track down.

Answer (score 4):

It is necessary to use either C11 or compiler extensions to align `vector_t`. For example, for a truly opaque type with flexible size and alignment, that means a declarator like this:

```
#define stack_alloc_opaque(identifier) \
    alignas(alignof(max_align_t)) char (identifier)[sizeof_opaque_type()]
```

Where `sizeof_opaque_type()` is a function returning the true size at runtime.

If you don't need the full flexibility of an opaque type you must at least align by `alignof(struct s_vector_private)`, but this limits your ability to alter the type behind the scenes.

While you could probably get away with the alignment mismatch on x86, it is undefined behavior to cast between pointers with different alignment requirements, and accessing such an object is definitely not portable.

Speaking of which, there's an elephant in the room here.

Doing the above will make the types perfectly compatible at the byte level, but it's skirting strict aliasing rules. The exception that that allows `char*` to alias any other type is one-way only -- `vector_t` being declared as `uint8_t[]` (or even `char[]`) makes that its effective type, so it can't be punned to something else. That leaves you with a few options:

- Use a compiler extension like `__attribute__((may_alias))` on `s_vector_private`
- Disable strict aliasing optimizations altogether (`-fno-strict-aliasing`)
- Leave them on, but test carefully with awareness that problems may occur in the future or in other configurations
- Don't use opaque types on the stack

Unfortunately the only really portable and safe one is the last. I like this approach too, but I don't know of any other way around that particular issue.

Comment: May I confirm. The Zmq approach is the safe and portable one? Due to the struct containing the vector, will it be aligned in any platform?

Comment: @fanl It looks like it's up to the user to align zmq_msg_t, or only allocate them with `malloc`. Otherwise, as it is it will have the same alignment as char (i.e. 1).

Comment: What if we changed the array of `vector_t` to int, would it align properly to the private struct? i.e: `typedef int vector_t[(sizeof(struct s_vector_private) / sizeof(int)) + ((sizeof(struct s_vector_private)%sizeof(int)?1:0)];`

Comment: @fanl depends on the platform. For instance, on x86_32 `s_vector_private` is 4 byte aligned like int, but on x86_64 it's 8 while int is still 4. You ought to be able to use the most strictly aligned type in the private struct (`size_t` or `uint8_t*` in this case). The problem is determining which that is portably. In C11 you can use `max_align_t` in place of `int` to guarantee strict enough alignment: `typedef max_align_t vector_t[(sizeof(struct s_vector_private)-1)/sizeof(max_align_t)+1];`

Answer (score 2):

The technique won't cause problems with heap allocations.  The pointer returned by `malloc()` et al is aligned sufficiently for any use — the `malloc()` function cannot tell whether it is allocating a 40-byte string that could be on any byte boundary or an array of a type that needs to be aligned on an 8-byte boundary, so it takes the conservative view that it is always allocating for the most stringent alignment that the implementation requires.

The technique could in theory cause problems with stack allocation.  If you have:

```
char     c1;
vector_t v1;
char     c2;
```

then you could have `v1` misaligned.  It probably won't be a problem, but if you wish to be safe, you avoid the possibility.  However, GCC 4.8.2 running on Mac OS X 10.9.1 seems to go to some lengths to avoid trouble:

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Werror alx.c -o alx
$ alx
24
&c1 = 0x7fff54b9552d
&v1 = 0x7fff54b95530
&c2 = 0x7fff54b9552e
&p1 = 0x7fff54b95550
&c3 = 0x7fff54b9552f
$ gcc -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Werror alx.c -o alx
$ alx
24
&c1 = 0x7fff579a756f
&v1 = 0x7fff579a7550
&c2 = 0x7fff579a754f
&p1 = 0x7fff579a7530
&c3 = 0x7fff579a752f
$
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct s_vector_private
{
    size_t item_size;
    uint32_t used_slots;
    uint32_t buffer_total_slots;
    uint8_t *buffer;
};
typedef uint8_t vector_t[sizeof(struct s_vector_private)];

int main(void)
{
    char c1;
    vector_t v1;
    char c2;
    struct s_vector_private p1;
    char c3;

    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(vector_t));
    printf("&c1 = %p\n", (void *)&c1);
    printf("&v1 = %p\n", (void *)&v1);
    printf("&c2 = %p\n", (void *)&c2);
    printf("&p1 = %p\n", (void *)&p1);
    printf("&c3 = %p\n", (void *)&c3);

    return 0;
}
```

Also, the technique is a trifle odd.  It hasn't really hidden the underlying type (the code can still see it); it just isn't called `vector_t`.

Answer (score -1):

There is not a problem here. To understand why, you need to see how `sizeof` works with `struct`s that do not have `__attribute__ ((__packed__))` or explicit alignment.

Try the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct st
{
  void *p;
  char c;
};

struct st arr[5];

int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  printf ("Size of struct: %lu\nSize of array: %lu\n",
      sizeof (struct st),
      sizeof (arr));
  exit (0);
}
```

The output is as follows (on x86_64):

```
Size of struct: 16
Size of array: 80
```

This marginally surprising result is because while `struct st` appears to need only 9 bytes (8 for the pointer, and one for the `char`), it actually takes 16 for precisely the reason that an array of them must have proper alignment. `sizeof` thus includes the padding bytes. Hence 5 of them take 80 bytes, and each of the pointers is correctly aligned.

Even within the structure, without `__attribute__ ((__packed__))`, padding bytes will be inserted to align the types properly (preventing this is precisely what `__attribute__ ((__packed__))` is for).

Re the ZMQ example, I am not familiar with the code, but I am guessing they are defining the wire format for a message, which is of constant byte size. At some point they will cast part or all of it to a structure, probably with `__attribute__ ((__packed__))`, being careful about what falls where. Why do this rather than just define a structure for the entire message? This may be so that if someone changes the `struct`, they get an immediate failure as opposed to a working but incompatible protocol. But that bit is just speculation.

Comment: Your answer is about sizes while the question is about alignment. Also you seem to have not understood the technique of the question.